# C#: Recursive functions with Lambdas

Tags: c#, recursion, lambda, factorial

The below does not compile:

```
Func<int, int> fac = n => (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1);
```

> Local variable 'fac' might not be
>   initialized before accessing

How can you make a recursive function with lambdas?

**[Update]**

Here are also two links that I found interesting to read:

1. [Eric Lippert's "Why does a recursive lambda cause a definite assignment error?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/why-does-a-recursive-lambda-cause-a-definite-assignment-error.aspx)
2. [Anonymous Recursion in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx)

Comment: Do you really want to? That looks like a nightmare for maintainability and understanding...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This particular style of function is not supported by C# as a single line declaration.  You have to separate out the declaration and definition into 2 lines

```
Func<int, int> fac = null;
fac = n => (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1);
```

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to create `fac` first und assign it later (which is pretty unfunctional because it depends on multiple assignment) or use so called [`Y-combinators`](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx).

Example:

```
delegate Func<TIn, TOut> FixedPointFunction<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> f);

static Func<T, TRes> Fix<T, TRes>(FixedPointFunction<T, TRes> f) {
    return f(x => Fix(f)(x));
}

static void Main(string[] args) {

    var fact = Fix<int, int>(f => x => (x <= 1) ? x : x * f(x - 1));

    Console.WriteLine(fact(5));            
}
```

But note that this might be somewhat hard to read/understand.

Answer (score -1):

Since C# 7.0 you finally **can** do a similar thing by using a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) instead of a lambda.

```
int fac(int n) => (n <= 1) ? 1 : n * fac(n - 1);
```

Comment: Local functions aren't lambdas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-functions-vs-lambda-expressions