# Can a Func<> call itself recursively?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

I was playing around with a [code golf question yesterday for building a christmas tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/code-golf-christmas-edition-how-to-print-out-a-christmas-tree-of-height-n) which came around last year and I threw together a quick recursive algorithm to do the job:

```
static string f(int n, int r)
{
    return "\n".PadLeft(2 * r, '*').PadLeft(n + r)
        + (r < n ? f(n, ++r) : "*".PadLeft(n));
}
```

I got to wondering if I could do the same thing with a Func:

```
Func<int,int,string> f = (n, r) => {
    return "\n".PadLeft(2 * r, '*').PadLeft(n + r) 
        + (r < n ? f(n, ++r) : "*".PadLeft(n));
};
```

This *would* do the job except that the recursive part doesn't recognize that the call to f is actually a call to itself.  This would lead me to conclude that a Func *can't* call itself recursively - but I wonder if I'm drawing false conclusions or if it can be done but requires a different approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079164/c-recursive-functions-with-lambdas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Func<int, int, string> f = null;
f = (x, y) => f(x, y);
```

Obviously this will cause a StackOverflowException, but you get the idea.

Comment: LOL - I get the gist of it.  It's too bad you can't do it all in a single line though.  Thanks.

Comment: Spot on. Ben's code is illegal for the same reasons as 'int i = i + 1;'

Also note that f's code block could reassign the value of f, which would be obtuse but perfectly legal.

Comment: Yeah - don't write this exact code, but it answers the question in principle

Comment: @Rob: In the case of your example `int i = i + 1` that makes sense what is the value of 'not initialized' + 1?  It seemed to me to be logical that 'f' is assigned the code block when calling `f = ...` but when calling f(n, r) it would actually be calling itself.  Given that f would need to have been initialized in order to for the code block to be executing to call itself, it makes logical sense that this would work (at least on a human level).

Comment: I describe the reason why this is an error here: 

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/why-does-a-recursive-lambda-cause-a-definite-assignment-error.aspx

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thank you Eric, I appreciate your attention.  Now go and make it work so my code can be even more elegant than it already is :P

Answer (score 5):

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2007/05/11/recursive-lambda-expressions.aspx) for a *very* geeky coverage of recursive lambdas, fixed points, Y-combinators, etc. Very interesting read.