# Problems with recursive generic type in c#

Tags: c#, generics, exception, recursion, mono

I've got some C# code that compiles fine under both mono and the Microsoft's .net compilers, but only runs on mono.
The error message is (newlines added by me)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException:
Could not load type 'Hasse.Groups.Heavy.Product.PowerGroup`1'
from assembly 'Hasse, Version=1.0.x.y, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
because it has recursive generic definition.
```

The type actually has a recursive generic definition, so my question is: why does it work with mono? [The code runs and produces the expected result]

Full source code is here: https://github.com/miniBill/Hasse

Reduced code which still crashes is here:

```
public class Group<T> : IWrappableGroup<WrapperGroup<T>> {}

public class WrapperElement<T> {}

public interface IWrappableGroup<U> {}

public class WrapperGroup<T> : Group<WrapperElement<T>> {}

class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        var ng = new Group<object>();
    }
}
```

Here is proof that it works on mono: http://ideone.com/ZvA3I

Comment: Rather than give us the link to a large project, it would be useful if you could *post* a short (minimal) but complete example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Let me try and create a minimal example

Comment: I've managed to reduce it a little bit further... mind if I edit? (I've been trying to reduce it until it's *really* minimal...)

Comment: Go ahead and do it. I had tried making it smaller, but couldn't :)

Comment: Done. Only a single executable statement...

Comment: Wow :O changed ideone link to new poc

Comment: its easy to see the recursion here. i never tried such a thing, but it sure does look like something you'd expect to crash :)

Comment: I'm more surprised that this works on Mono..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679421/generic-defintion-causes-system-typeloadexception) issue.  It could be reported as a compiler error.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf (page 129)

As for working in Mono, there are several places where Mono working is "broken" as far as the specs is concerned.

([Recursive lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079164/c-recursive-functions-with-lambdas/1079609#1079609) are another exmaple of something that works in Mono that shouldn't)

Comment: Thank you. Although I suspect that it works in Mono for the same reason Recursive lambdas do: it may explode, but it may make sense (like my code did)

Comment: Can you file the "recursive lambdas" issue in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ please?