# Not have to intially assign a generic delegate when attempting to use it recursively

Tags: c#, generics, recursion, delegates

I've just discovered Generic delegates in C# and was thinking if they could be used recursively, I came up with this simple piece which just returns a string of Fibonacci numbers up to a limit.

```
Func<int, int, string, string> Fibonanci;
Fibonanci = delegate( int a, int b, string c )
{
    return "";
};
Fibonanci = delegate( int a, int b, string c )
{
    if( ( a == 0 ) && ( b == 0 ) )
    {
        b = 1;
        c += ( "0" + ( a.ToString() + b.ToString() ) ); 
    }
    else
    {
        c += ( a + b ).ToString();
    }

    if( ( a >= limit ) || ( b >= limit ) )
    {
        return ( c );
    }
    else
    {
        return Fibonanci( b, ( b + a ), c );
    }
};
```

Here is my code, it runs fine, the question I'm asking is if there is a way to remove the first assignment(I get errors say I've used an unassigned variable)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Recursive functions with Lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079164/c-recursive-functions-with-lambdas)

Answer (score 1):

You could technically assign it like this:

```
Func<int, int, string, string> Fibonanci = null;
```

That would keep you from having to do this:

```
Fibonanci = delegate( int a, int b, string c )
{
    return "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Fibonanci declaraion... assign it to null...

```
Func<int, int, string, string> Fibonanci = null;

Fibonanci = delegate(int a, int b, string c)
{
    if ((a == 0) && (b == 0))
    {
        b = 1;
        c += ("0" + (a.ToString() + b.ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        c += (a + b).ToString();
    }

    if ((a >= limit) || (b >= limit))
    {
        return (c);
    }
    else
    {
        return Fibonanci(b, (b + a), c);
    }
};
```

I cant tell you why this is the case, but i have encountered many times!

Comment: Inside the variable initializer, the variable has not yet been assigned.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/why-does-a-recursive-lambda-cause-a-definite-assignment-error.aspx